# Displaying a border around a mask actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to display a border around the shape that is being used as a mask over an image? I've created a custom shape using points and set it as the mask over an image... But when i set it as the mask the lines between the points disappear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a *shape / sprite / mc / bitmap* and you are using on of them as a mask, no matter what graphics they will have, you will not be able to see any. in the [docs](http://goo.gl/tcTf4) it is said:

> The mask object itself is not drawn

so solution for that one is:

- bordered graphics
- mask
- masked item

where your bordered graphics is the same size as mask and has border properties.